# How do I update the tab bar badge in React-Native using react-navigation without the navigation being reloaded?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm working on a React-Native application and want to start adding a few extra features like tab bar badges for unread notification and message count.

I am using react-navigation for the tab bar and redux for my state store. I have an unread count in my notification and message states that I am retrieving and using to show the tab bar badge currently in the navigator.

The issue I am having is that I want to decrement the unread count if the user taps on a message or notification (marking it as read). When I do this it reloads the navigation throwing the user back to the main navigation from the screen they are currently on.

I have created a snack showing the issue by having the notification and message details screen have a button that decrements the unread count.

https://snack.expo.dev/@simplytrak/tab-bar-badges

How do I keep the user on the current screen but also update the badge on the tab bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating components inside your `AppNavigator` component. You need to move them outside.

> Sometimes you might have noticed that your screens unmount/remount, or your local component state or the navigation state resets when you navigate. This might happen if you are creating React components during render.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#screens-are-unmountingremounting-during-navigation

Comment: Thanks, @satya164 that worked a treat, I broke each navigation part into its own component!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is "best practice", but I was also able to manually update the badge count by using `setOptions()` on the `navigation` prop inside my screen component. This code snippet updates the badge count whenever the state variable, `count`, changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      tabBarBadge: count,
    });
  }, [navigation, count]);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/